# How can I trigger a hadoop workflow using results from an Sql query?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, sqoop, oozie

I have a complex workflow in Hadoop using **Sqoop -> Pig+MR -> Hive**.

This flow should be triggered once some specific Oracle table is updated with log data, pertaining the completion of a previous ETL process.

This main workflow is comprised in Oozie. I'd like to also use Oozie to trigger the process when necessary, since Oozie is the most established workflow scheduler at my organization.

My ideal (hypothetical) solution:

**1- An oozie job which runs every X minutes and executes a Sql statement.** 
**According to the results of the statement, the job triggers (or not), with parameters:**

**2- An oozie job which executes the main workflow**

so,

- Is this possible with Oozie?
- Should I implement this in Oozie?
- How would you implement it?

Thanks,
Ron

ps - I'm using CHD5.2

Answer (score 0):

What if you create 2 coordinators, the first just read the Oracle an produce some output (if your data available in the Ora), what could be used as an input event of the second coordinator?
This is a kind of implicit trigger.